# SSH connection to Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, ssh, nuget, libraries

I am writing a code to connect to Raspberries. I have about 100 devices. Some of them are on  Raspbian 8 (Jessie), some 9 (Stretch) and some 10 (Buster). The code should be able to connect and reboot the device or show the last chormium page it has been on.

```
SshClient sshclient = new SshClient(label2.Text, "pi", psw);
        try
        {
            sshclient.Connect();
            SshCommand sc = sshclient.CreateCommand("strings ~/.config/chromium/Default/'Current Session' | 'grep' -E '^https?://'");
            sc.Execute();
            string answer = sc.Result;
            int index2 = answer.LastIndexOf("http");
            textBox1.Text = answer.Substring(index2);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        sshclient.Disconnect();
```

This is part of the code, which should show me last visited page. The code is working perfectly fine, the command is working fine,  problem is I can connect this way only to the devices which have Raspebian 8 or 9. Devices with Raspbian 10 show error, that I can't connect. But when I am using putty.exe i can connect and even do the command.

So let's just say there's nothing wrong with settings in Raspian 10 raspberries. I tried to download different NuGet libraries - Neon.SSH.NET for example (coz the most downloaded SSH.NET was uploaded 3 or 4 years ago), but the Neon.SSH.NET, when downloaded, show me errors in code. It doesnt know SshClient. I tried add it to using, but using doesn't know it.

Have someone used Neon.SSH.NET? Are there special commands I dont know about? Or is there any better library than old SSH.NET? It's weird I can connect to 8 and 9 but not to 10 (which putty can). And no, installing 8 or 9 to 10 version devices is not an option, actually I have to update all of 8 and 9 devices in close future.

Comment: When it fails to connect, what is the exact exception that you're getting?

Comment: Hi, it's {"An established connection was aborted by the server."}. I tried to do some changes, previous exception was "...was aborted by the host". Which, pretty much, should be the same/similar.

Comment: Problem solved. The problem was in old SSH. Downloaded beta update - https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/2020.0.0-beta1 and it's working.